# How to use json to extract contents from a text/javascript

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi everyone I'm trying to use json python library to extract contents from a text/javascript but unsuccessfully.

This is my code:

```
js = soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})[15]
js = json.loads(str(js).split('var item_stock = ')[1]).split('colors: ')[1].split('sizes: ')[1]
for size in js:
    sizee = str(size).split("size_name")[1].split(":")[1]
    print(sizee)
```

And this is the text/javascript:

```
var item_stock = {"colors": [{"color_code": "1","color_name": "BLACK","color_swatch": "/apis/image/crop?file_name=%2Fphoto%2F2019aw%2F19-04969%2Fs-19-04969_1-1.jpg&width=26&height=26","color_proper": "3,600","color_proper_usd": "33.48","color_proper_eur": "30.24","color_sale": "","color_sale_usd": "","color_sale_eur": "","color_percent": "","html_color": "","image_url": "","stock":  "0","sizes": [{"goods_id": "821","size_code": "OS","size_name": "23-25cm","stock": 0,"size_proper": "3,600","size_proper_usd": "33.48","size_proper_eur": "30.24","size_sale": "","size_sale_usd": "","size_sale_eur": "","size_percent": "","in_sales_flag": "1","stock_request_flag": "","restock_request_flag": 0,"coming_soon_flag": "0",},],"images": "<img src=/photo/2019aw/19-04969/s-19-04969_1-1.jpg>",},{"color_code": "101","color_name": "WHITE","color_swatch": "/apis/image/crop?file_name=%2Fphoto%2F2019aw%2F19-04969%2Fs-19-04969_101-1.jpg&width=26&height=26","color_proper": "3,600","color_proper_usd": "33.48","color_proper_eur": "30.24","color_sale": "","color_sale_usd": "","color_sale_eur": "","color_percent": "","html_color": "","image_url": "","stock":  "3","sizes": [{"goods_id": "822","size_code": "OS","size_name": "23-25cm","stock": 3,"size_proper": "3,600","size_proper_usd": "33.48","size_proper_eur": "30.24","size_sale": "","size_sale_usd": "","size_sale_eur": "","size_percent": "","in_sales_flag": "1","stock_request_flag": "","restock_request_flag": 0,"coming_soon_flag": "0",},],"images": "<img src=/photo/2019aw/19-04969/s-19-04969_101-1.jpg>",},]};
```

I'm trying to print out "size_name": "23-25cm" and "color_name": "BLACK"

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @Itay Zagron syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Once you "json.loads", you cannot use split or any other string methods.

try this:

```
js = soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})[15]
js_dict = json.loads(str(js).split('var item_stock = ')[1])
colors = js_dict.get("colors")

for color in colors:
    color_name = color.get("color_name")
    sizes = color.get("sizes")
    for size in sizes:
        print(f"color: {color}, size: {size.get("size_name")}")
```

Comment: @notme17 your json is invalid, therefore you are not able to "loads".
You have to fix it before.

Answer (score 0):

@Italy Zagron I haven’t resolved!